# Jenkins - How to make a job trigger 3 jobs on 3 different node simultaneously

Tags: jenkins

I am relatively new to Jenkins and not aware of many plugins available. I would need little help in solving one of my scenario.

I have a job (master) triggers 3 different jobs( A, B and C). I would need to trigger these 3 jobs on 3 different nodes and these node names I can not hard code but need to pass from master job.

So, my master job reads these values as parameters from user and triggers A, B and C jobs

Any help on this is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one solution using [Jenkins Join](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Join+Plugin) plugin and the [Jenkins NodeLabel](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/NodeLabel+Parameter+Plugin) plugin.

On your master job, add a one node parameter per child job:

[image]

[image]

Next, add a new join post-build action to trigger the child jobs using the [Parameterized Trigger](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin) plugin (add the "Current Build parameters" option):

[image]

It will trigger the job test.bruno.A and test.bruno.B and pass the 2 node parameters to these jobs (NODE_A and NODE_B).

On the child jobs, you just have to add a Node parameter with the same name (NODE_A and NODE_B):

[image]

(same for job B...)

When you trigger the master job, you select the target nodes for your 2 jobs:

[image]

Your child jobs will use the relevant nodes:

[image]

[image]

I hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks for the solution.. I do not have "Join Plugin" to test this out. However I have found a solution to this. I have created 3 String parameters in master job and passed it to child jobs using "NodeLabel" parameter.

Comment: OK thanks for the update and nice to hear you found a solution!